# Rxjava while loop to get database object and upload to server

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm confused about how to implement this in RxJava.
I would like to

1. take an object from my database
2. upload it
3. delete it from the database
4. take the next item from the database and repeat 2 and 3
5. complete when the database has no objects remaining

I know how to do this via loading all objects from the database at first and creating an `Observable` like this `Observable.fromIterable(allMyDbObjects)`, however I would like to take objects one at a time, in case the database is updated while I'm uploading.
I can't figure out how to do this. I've looked at `repeatUntil` but it just seems to repeat instantly. Here is pseudocode for what I'm thinking:

```
getFirstDbObject()
    .flatMapCompletable { obj ->
        upload(obj)
            .doOnComplete {
                 deleteFromDb(obj)
            }
    }
    .repeatUntil {
        // dbIsEmptyLogic. 
        // This doesn't work. I need to somehow call getFirstDbObject() again
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getFirstDbObject()` returns a Maybe, you can achieve this by mapping the result to a boolean (`true` if the database is empty, `false` if not) and then repeating the sequence until `getFirstDbObject()` returns empty and the stream completes.

```
getFirstDbObject()
    .toObservable()
    .flatMapSingle { obj ->
        upload(obj)
            .doOnComplete { deleteFromDb(obj) } // probably better to use .andThen(deleteFromDb(obj)) if delete also returns a completable
            .toSingleDefault(false)
    }
    .defaultIfEmpty(true)
    .repeat()
    .takeUntil { isComplete ->
        isComplete
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution in my code base.

```
    val source = HashSet<String>()
    source.add("a")
    source.add("b")
    source.add("c")
    source.add("d")
    source.add("e")
    io.reactivex.Observable.just(Unit)
        .flatMap { it ->
            io.reactivex.Observable.fromCallable {
                println("first flatmap print $it")
                // uploadObj()
                source.first()
            }
        }.flatMap {
            // delete
            io.reactivex.Observable.fromCallable {
                source.remove(it)
                println("second flatmap remove $it")
                // delete object
            }
        }
        .repeatUntil { source.isEmpty() }
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: That's not too bad, but i'd rather not have to call `getFirstDbObject()` in 2 places